# php function that triggers an alert in a drop down/select box

Tags: php, javascript

Here is the html for my select box:

```
<select class=" reason_swap" id="call_type" name="call_type">
<option value=""></option>
<option title="OK - NO CHANGES" selected="" value="NC">OK - NO CHANGES</option>
<option title="OK - PENDING AUTH" value="PA">OK - PENDING AUTH</option>
<option title="OK - PENDING INS" value="IN">OK - PENDING INS</option>
<option title="OK - PENDING INS/PO" value="PI">OK - PENDING INS/PO</option>
<option title="OK - PENDING PO" value="PO">OK - PENDING PO</option></select>
```

I'm using this refocus function to make these three fields mandatory.

```
if ($this->call_type == 'NC' && $this->times_testing == '') $this->refocus('times_testing');
        if ($this->call_type == 'PA' && $this->times_testing == '') $this->refocus('times_testing');
        if ($this->call_type == 'IN' && $this->times_testing == '') $this->refocus('times_testing');
```

The only problem i'm having is i'm just being picky about how the alert is getting thrown, since there is only 5 options and i'm alerting if three of the five do not match the criteria, i just want to do it the other way around...

If it's not PI or PO than alert/refocus **on post**.

I figured it would be simple.. something like this:

```
if (!$this->call_type == 'PI' && !$this->call_type == 'PO' && $this->times_testing == '') $this->refocus('times_testing');
```

but to no avail, it didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the refocus function:

```
protected function refocus($name, $msg = '')
        {
        if (!$name) return;
        $this->halt = 1;
        $out = $msg ? $msg : _to_caps($name) . " is required...";
        $nest = $this->nest ? $this->nest . $name : $name; // no brackets on the name here since not allowed in HTML ids
        \Message::add("$out<input type='hidden' value='$nest' id='__refocus'>", 'not_ok');
        }
```

Comment: I think you want to use JavaScript here.

Comment: What is `$this`?  What alert is getting thrown, where?  What is `->refocus`?

Comment: the alert pertains to another field for times testing...it pops up in a modal window and says "Times Testing is required..." when they try and submit if one of those three codes are selected.

Comment: $this is part of the construct.. just refers to part of the patient object that i'm using. I'm not sure if that really answered your question though, you must of known that.. can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, and refocus is just a class build and renamed ... it's nearly identical to the javascript function focus()... if there is a mandatory field and it's not filled in.. it highlights the field that needs data.

Comment: I added the refocus function to give more detail, hopefully someone can still provide some insight to this daunting problem at hand. =]

Comment: You should use [jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif).

Comment: I tried something like so:   var MyColumn = document.getElementById("call_type");
   MyColumn.onchange = function(){if (MyColumn.value == "PI") {alert('hi');}};  and it works but not properly, i need it to alert only after it's been posted/saved.